# How is golden ratio related to fractals (if it really is)?

Tags: fractals

I came across an information that the golden ratio is related to fractals in way a that:

"Fractal patterns created using the golden ratio, however, are optimized in a way that does not occur with any other number"

or sth like that. But such enigmatic phrases tell me completaly nothing.

So, if the golden ratio is really somehow connected with fractals what is the connection and how could it be stated precisely? If someone knows the answer or know a source where I could find it I would very thankfull.

Comment: The quote appears in an answer to the Quora question ["How is the golden ratio related to fractals?"](https://www.quora.com/How-is-the-golden-ratio-related-to-fractals). The answer gives a sample illustration, which may-or-may-not satisfactorily justify the statement.

Comment: It's just one example. Assuming it is correct. And it's certainly far too less to be a satisfactionary answer.

Comment: There are some fractals related to golden ratio, such as [Golden Dragon](https://larryriddle.agnesscott.org/ifs/heighway/goldenDragon.htm)